# How to use this.field_manager.set_field_value

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo

I want to modify some values using "field_manager" of `FormWidget`.

Here is my code:

```
openerp.new_payrolls = function (instance) {
   instance.web.client_actions.add('example.action','instance.new_payrolls.Action');
   instance.new_payrolls.Action = instance.web.Widget.extend({
       template: 'new_payrolls.action',
       events: { 
          'click .oe_web_example_file button': 'Upload',
          'click .oe_web_example_load button': 'momo_change', 
       }, 
       init: function () {
           this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var self = this;
        this._start = null;
        this._watch = null;
        var Model = new instance.web.Model('new_payrolls'); 
      },
      start: function () {
          this._super();
          console.log('Data Loading');
          var self = this;
          this.field_manager.on("field_changed:matricule", this);
          var data = this.field_manager.get_field_value("matricule"); // matricule is an attribute from new_payrolls class
     }, 
}
```

Then i want to use `this.field_manager.set_values(matricule).
Error: : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Comment: Is here anyone whow can give me a simple example using his.field_manager.set_values with javascript in openerp.